# Exclude duplicate values from array

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an array which returns a set of events for the specific month. Some months can have different events on the same day. How do I detect duplicate dates and show both the events under the same date entries rather than two separate date entries.

**Code:**

```
public void setListView(int month, int year, int dv) {

        events = new HolidayEvents();
        _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        int totalDays = _calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        for(int i = 1; i <= totalDays; i++){
            if(isHoliday(i, month, year, dv))
            {
                date = i + " " + getMonthForInt(month-1) + " " + year;

                for (Event event : events.eventDetails(this, month, i) 
                {
                       summaries.add(new Summary(date, event.eventdetails));

                } 
            }
        }
}
```

**Output:**

11 January has two events. So it displays the result:

```
11 January 2013 
-Event Name-
11 January 2013
-Event Name-
```

I would like the output to show like this:

```
11 January 2013
-Event Name | Event Name-
```

Comment: What about a `Map` `Date` as keys and `List<Event>` as values?

Comment: @MrSmith42, can you show an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store your `Event`s in in a structure like this:

```
Map<Date, List<Event>> eventMap= new HashMap<Date,List<Event>>();
```

you can get all event for a given date `d` like this:

```
List<Event> events = eventMap.get(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ListMultiMap<Date,Event> eventMap = ArrayListMultiMap<Date,Event>.create();
```

Puts to the multimap will add the event to the list of events for that date. Getting with a date will return a list with all events for the date.

You can also do this manually with a regular map though it is a bit more cumbersome.

http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html